# javascript on jsp not working?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the problem where the its not checking the text i enter is letter only or not ? I dont really know how to write javascript in jsp, and Ajax too? can someone help by posting a good link that i can learn? especially using Ajax to call database

here is the problems i have right now, also how can i check the text size is bigger than 0

```
<%@page import="java.util.*,support.*,java.sql.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<%//javascript file %>
<script>
function allLetter(value)  
{  
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
 if(inputtxt.value.match(alphaExp))  
   {  
    return true;  
   }  
 else  
   {  
   alert("message");  
   return false;  
   }  
}  
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Names and country of residence page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

    // Registering Postgresql JDBC driver with the DriverManager
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    // Open a connection to the database using DriverManager
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/assignment1",
        "postgres","Km81920265");


        // Create the statement
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        // Use the created statement to SELECT
        // the student attributes FROM the Student table.
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM countries_and_states WHERE is_country='t'");


%>

<%//first delcare input %>
Please enter your first name, last name and middle initial:<p>
<form method="get" action="address.jsp">
<%//store input into session %>
Your first name :<input type="text" size="15" name="firstName" onchange="allLetter(this.value); "/><p/>
Your last name  :  <input type="text" size="15" name="lastName"/><p/>
Your middle name:<input type="text" size="15" name="middleName"/><p/>

<%//display dropdown menu using for looop %>
Provide country information menu:<p>
Country:
<select name="Countryid">

<%




while(rs.next()){
%>
<option value="<%=rs.getInt("cs_id")%>"><%=rs.getString("country_state")%>
</option>
<%} %>
</select>

<p>
<%-- -------- Close Connection Code -------- --%>
            <%
                // Close the ResultSet
                if(rs != null){
                    rs.close();
                }

                // Close the Statement
                statement.close();

                // Close the Connection
                conn.close();


 %>

<%///closing up the entry page and submit the data %>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Personal Data" onclick="this.disabled=true;"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the input element to allLetter. You should write the method like this.

```
function allLetter(inputtxt)  
{  
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
 if(inputtxt.value.match(alphaExp))  
   {  
    return true;  
   }  
 else  
   {  
   alert("message");  
   return false;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: so how does the function know which input text? since i need to check all the name

Comment: Won't work because OP sends value not object `onchange="allLetter(this.value);`

Comment: so how can i send it to the function?

Comment: You can do `onchange="allLetter(this);"` on the input element or follow @MuthuKumaran's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I changed `inputtxt.value` to `value`.

```
function allLetter(value)  
{  
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
 if(value.match(letters))  //removed inputtxt and added `letters`
   {  
    return true;  
   }  
 else  
   {  
   alert("message");  
   return false;  
   }  
}  ​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H44j6/

**UPDATE**

Change this line

```
Your first name :<input type="text" size="15" name="firstName" onchange="allLetter(this.value); "/><p/>
```

to

```
Your first name :<input type="text" size="15" name="firstName" onkeydown="allLetter(this.value); "/><p/>
```

**or**

```
Your first name :<input type="text" size="15" name="firstName" onblur="allLetter(this.value); "/><p/>
```

Comment: no... it still doesnt work.... so how can i pass the input value to the function?

Comment: You already passing the value. How do you know it's not working? Also you are using `onchange` in the textbox, try using `onblur` or `onkeydown` or `onkeypress`

Comment: Check here it's working http://jsfiddle.net/H44j6/. There was a error in your script and I corrected the issue.

Comment: nope, what was the problem? also i have a question... so this.value is mean the firstName

Comment: `this.value` means the value typed inside the textbox.

Comment: how can i check if the this.value contains alteast one letter before i enter the second text ?